# rvm gemdir gives error ~/.rvm/scripts/gemsets: line 786: rvm command not found

Tags: ruby, rvm

I get an "rvm: command not found error" on rvm gemdir, but only when I'm using one of the rvm ruby installations.  I get the same result with 1.9.2 and 1.8.7 (the only ones I've tried):

```
$ rvm install 1.8.7
...
Installation of rubygems completed successfully.
...
Install of ruby-1.8.7-p334 - #complete 

# works ok using system ruby
$ rvm gemdir
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8

$ rvm use 1.8.7
Using /Users/aneil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334

#
# HERE IS THE ERROR:
#
$ rvm gemdir
/Users/aneil/.rvm/scripts/gemsets: line 786: rvm: command not found
/Users/aneil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334

$ rvm use system
Now using system ruby.

$ rvm gemdir
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
```

Any ideas what's going on here?  Should I be concerned?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running

```
rvm get latest
```

from shell. addressed the issue for me.